# Creating a column in SQL based on condition across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to create a column in SQL table with the column names of those fields that match a condition(columns that contain value 1 for a TID)

Here the first table gives the SQL table I want to work on. And the below one gives the output I am expecting

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for the community to better help you post your SQL code, and try to learn using tutorials and post your progress here!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You say you want the "names of those columns that match", however your expected output only shows a single column name even when two or three columns match the value 1. So what is it? Just one column name (which one if multiple match?) or indeed a list of column names? Also: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: I want to create a column called 'MatchedFields' which will contain the column names where value is 1 for that TID. So for TID 101 (Field1, Field2, Field3) is (0,1,1) so I want TID 101 to have two records with MatchedFields column giving Field2 ad Field3. I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The two additional columns that you are trying to create don't have any new information that isn't already present or can't be computed already. 
The two columns can be thought of as a result of a function with which takes in the original 5 columns, gives in some result.
You can should take a look at [virtual columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_column). Your use case should be solved with it.

More specifically if you are using Postgres , refer [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) and [this](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/overview-generated-columns-postgresql).

And [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot using `cross apply` and filter:

```
select t.*, v.*
from t outer apply
     (values ('field1', field1), ('field2', field2), ('field3', field3), ('none', 0)
     ) v(matchedfield, counter)
where (matchedfield = 'none' and field1 + field2 + field3 = 0) or
      (matchedfield <> 'none' and field1 + field2 + field3 > 0) ;
```